# Prevent End Date Before Start Date and Vice Versa in dateRangeInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `dateRangeInput` in which I want to prevent the user from entering a start date that exceeds the end date and an end date that precedes a start date.

I have my `dateRangeInput` in the UI.  I then take the inputs into an `observe` in the `server` to validate and make the end date and start date equal if the user enters a start date after the end date or an end date before the start date.

I can't figure out how to get the modified start or end date back to input if the end before start  or start after end conditions are violated.

Code is below.  It is straightforward.  No code for returning the values to input.  Lost on that.  Thought about using `updateDateRangeInput` but didn't seem right.

Please help.

I have my UI code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
          fluidRow(dateRangeInput(
                             inputId = "mu_date_range",
                             label = "Select Registration Date Range",
                             start = "2021-01-01",
                             end = Sys.Date(),
                             min = "2021-01-01",
                             max = Sys.Date(),
                             format = 'M yyyy',
                             startview = 'year',
                             separator = '-')
          )
          )
```

And I'm putting an `observe()` function in `server` to check the validity of my dates:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

observe({

  if(mu_date_range[1] <= mu_date_range[2]){
    start <- mu_date_range[1]
  }else{
    start <- mu_date_range[2]
  }

  if(mu_date_range[2] >= mu_date_range[1]){
    end <- mu_date_range[2]
  }else{
    end <- mu_date_range[1]
  }

 })
}
```

I can't figure out how to then get these validate dates back to input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach using `reactiveValues`. You can store your start and end dates in `reactiveValues` and then use `observe` to compare with the date range input. The input is also dynamically created in `server` instead of `ui` and references the `reactiveValues`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <-fluidPage(
  uiOutput("date_range")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(start = as.Date("2021-01-01"), end = as.Date(Sys.Date()))
  
  observe({
    req(input$mu_date_range)
    
    dates <- as.Date(input$mu_date_range)
    
    if(dates[1] < rv$end) {
      rv$start <- dates[1]
    } else {
      rv$start <- rv$end
    }

    if(dates[2] > rv$start) {
      rv$end <- dates[2]
    } else {
      rv$end <- rv$start
    }
  })
  
  output$date_range <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput(
      inputId = "mu_date_range",
      label = "Select Registration Date Range",
      start = rv$start,
      end = rv$end,
      min = "2020-01-01",
      max = "2021-12-31",
      format = 'M yyyy',
      startview = 'year',
      separator = '-')
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: While both answers are great solutions to my question,  this one wins "best" as it nicely minimizes the code in UI and moves all the calculations to the server

Comment: I get an error with this solution `Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: @EricScott Try changing the `max` in `dateRangeInput` to a date later than today's date or `rv$end`. Otherwise, will have `NA` for the end date which was causing a problem.

Answer (score 1):

`updateDateRangeInput` is the way to go. First, you need to use `input$mu_date_range` to access values of the `dateRangeInput`. Later, according to your validation code, if a user selects an end date after the start date, the start and end dates are going to swap, which I think is a good validation. However, if you want to have the same date after a user selects an invalid date range, you need to use only the valid date as start and end dates. Below is a working code where both options are enabled.

```R
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput(
    inputId = "mu_date_range",
    label = "Select Registration Date Range",
    start = "2021-01-01",
    end = Sys.Date(),
    min = "2021-01-01",
    max = Sys.Date(),
    format = 'M yyyy',
    startview = 'year',
    separator = '-'),
  fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("value"))),
  dateRangeInput(
    inputId = "mu_date_range2",
    label = "Select Registration Date Range",
    start = "2021-01-01",
    end = Sys.Date(),
    min = "2021-01-01",
    max = Sys.Date(),
    format = 'M yyyy',
    startview = 'year',
    separator = '-'),
  fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("value2")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$mu_date_range })
  output$value2 <- renderPrint({ input$mu_date_range2 })
  
  observeEvent(input$mu_date_range, {
    mu_date_range <- input$mu_date_range
    if(mu_date_range[1] <= mu_date_range[2]){
      start <- mu_date_range[1]
    }else{
      start <- mu_date_range[2]
    }
    
    if(mu_date_range[2] >= mu_date_range[1]){
      end <- mu_date_range[2]
    }else{
      end <- mu_date_range[1]
    }
    
    updateDateRangeInput(
      session,
      "mu_date_range",
      start = start,
      end = end
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$mu_date_range2, {
    mu_date_range <- input$mu_date_range2
    if(mu_date_range[1] > mu_date_range[2]){
      mu_date_range[1] <- mu_date_range[2]
    }
    
    if(mu_date_range[2] < mu_date_range[1]){
      mu_date_range[2] <- mu_date_range[1]
    }
    
    updateDateRangeInput(
      session,
      "mu_date_range2",
      start = mu_date_range[1],
      end = mu_date_range[2]
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.   Glancing at it I never would have figured it out myself.   Will study it to make sure I understand and may hit you back with questions.